# Updating PHP Shopping Card Data via $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, session-variables, shopping-cart

I'm having trouble with updating the product quantity in my shopping cart.
I use an array, `$productArray`, to store the `product_id`, `product_name`, `quantity`, and `product_price` from database. I then check if there is already a product with that Product ID in my `$_SESSION`. If yes, then update quantity, if not, merge it into `$_SESSION`.

The issue here is that I'm not able to reach the code where it checks where the `product_id` is already in the session variable, hence it keeps merging the same product to the shopping cart instead of updating the quantity.

My code is below. Please let me know if there are any additional components I should include with my post. Thanks.

```
case "add":
    if(!empty($_POST["qty"])) {
        $productById = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM products WHERE  product_id= " . $_GET["pid"]);

$productArray = array($productById[0] ["product_id"]=>array('product_name'=>$productById[0]["product_name"], 'product_id'=>$productById[0]["product_id"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["qty"], 'product_price'=>$productById[0]["product_price"]));

        if (!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            if (in_array([$productById[0]["product_id"]],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                    if ($productById[0]["product_id"] == $k)
                        $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["qty"];
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$productArray);
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $productArray;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: What is the structure of `$_SESSION["cart_item"]`?

Comment: please dont use all caps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `in_array([$productById[0]["product_id"]],$_SESSION["cart_item"])` will always return `false` in your case.

You should change it to `isset($productById[0]["product_id"], $_SESSION["cart_item"])` I guest that you save each product info as an element with the key is the product id inside the `$_SESSION["cart_item"]` array.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the code and found that the your $_SESSION["cart_item"]  variable will be as

```
array(
    11=>array('product_name'=>'abc', 'product_id'=>11, 'quantity'=>2, 'product_price'=>20.00)
    12=>array('product_name'=>'xyz', 'product_id'=>12, 'quantity'=>3, 'product_price'=>23.22)
);
```

so you have to replace the

```
 if(in_array([$productById[0]["product_id"]],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
```

from

```
 if(in_array([$productById[0]["product_id"]],array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
```

This will work.